# Running a web server on an Android application

Tags: php, android, mysql, apache, web

There are some similar android app in google play store, like [KSWEB](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.kslabs.ksweb&hl=en).
It can supply *lighttpd, nginx, PHP, MySQL and FTP*.

I want to develop a similar android application. How can this be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web Server for Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509851/web-server-for-android)

Comment: if its already available then why you need to develop .. and lets say you want to develop what is the use ?? and how much did you worked and are you facing issue  then ask that specific issue

Comment: check this link https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd