# Web Server container for web application in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, webserver

I want to move my web application into an android app. I have the WebView set up and it is working but some of the script must be handled on on a web server. Is there any way to contain my web app in a webserver so I can set the webView URL to something like: localhost:8080/index.html.

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean something like this: https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/index.html Otherwise, you are going to have to clarify what you want.

Comment: What language is your web application written in? Php? Java? Python? Javascript? etc.

Comment: The script is in php and there is also a javascript file that needs to be served from a webserver or i'll get a cross-origin error

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509851/web-server-for-android